# URL manipulation in php

Tags: php

I have a table called `blogtable` where I have two fields. One is `title` and the other is `content`. I retrieved the only `title` rows in the form of links and saved it in a file called result.php.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
$data = mysql_query("select title from blogtable");

while($col = mysql_fetch_field($data))
{
    echo $col->name;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($data))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++)
    {
        echo"<br/>";
        echo "<a href=\"".$row[$i]."\">".$row[$i]."</a>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

I want to retrieve particular `title` along with `content` by using URL manipulation. I tried this but I don't know how to pass file URL. I wrote the following and the file name is parse.php.

```
<?php
$a = $_GET['title'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
$sqlstmt=select * from blogtable where title=$a;
mysql_query($sqlstmt);
?>
```

I am not getting how to parse the results.php URL and retrieve the data dynamically.

Comment: How does your url looks?

Comment: Its in the form of url="" but how to retrieve the values dynamically from results.php @kishor Subedi

Answer (score 1):

In your results.php file instead of:

```
echo "<a href=\"".$row[$i]."\">".$row[$i]."</a>";
```

Use:

```
echo "<a href=\"parse.php?title=".$row[$i]."\">".$row[$i]."</a>";
```

to use the `$_GET['title']` in your "parse.php".

This is one of the simplest way.

And in "parse.php" you have to change:

```
$sqlstmt=select * from blogtable where title=$a;
```

To:

```
$sqlstmt = "select * from blogtable where title='".$a."'";
```

Then you can manipulate your detail, after fetching it from database.

**A suggestion:**

Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql.

Comment: Yes but i have to spectify the file path and the onclick event i am not getting how to do that in this code <?php
$a=$_GET['title'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
$sqlstmt=select * from blogtable where title=$a;
mysql_query($sqlstmt);

?>

Comment: What do you want on "onclick event", could you explain?

Comment: Yes Kishore . first thing i have two fields in my table one is title and other is content .In result.php i have displayed all the links related to title (in the form of links) .Now my question is if there is a title abc and content def when i click abc in my results.php a new page should be displayed along with that content def

Comment: You have a mistake in preparing query statement in result.php. Please check the answer.

Comment: Yes i corrected it and executed it is getting as http://localhost/parse.php?title=abc and an error in the file parse.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31110/discussion-between-kishor-subedi-and-shashank)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31117/discussion-between-shashank-and-kishor-subedi)